# Magento data upgrade won't run

Tags: php, magento, module, attributes

We have an attribute that was created in a previous upgrade statement we would now like to remove. It was originally created with the following script:

```
<?php
    $installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

    $installer->startSetup();

    $vCustomerEntityType = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
    $vCustAttributeSetId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeSetId($vCustomerEntityType);
    $vCustAttributeGroupId = $installer->getDefaultAttributeGroupId($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId);

    $installer->addAttribute('customer', 'custom_id', array(
        'label' => 'Custom ID',
        'input' => 'text',
        'type'  => 'varchar',
        'forms' => array('adminhtml_customer'),
        'required' => 0,
        'user_defined' => 1,
    ));

    $installer->addAttributeToGroup($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustAttributeSetId, $vCustAttributeGroupId, 'custom_id', 0);

    $oAttribute = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'custom_id');
    $oAttribute->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'));
    $oAttribute->save();

    $installer->endSetup();
```

The above has served us well, but we no longer need this custom_id. So, I have created the following upgrade:

```
<?php

    $installer = new Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');

    $installer->startSetup();

    $vCustomerEntityType = $installer->getEntityTypeId('customer');
    $vCustomerCustomIdAttribute = $install->getAttribute($vCustomerEntityType, 'custom_id');

    $installer->removeAttribute($vCustomerEntityType, $vCustomerCustomIdAttribute);

    $installer->endSetup();
```

I save this and I figure it should simply remove this attribute, but it does not. I go to the admin section and the field and data are still there. I have attempted to clear the magento cache and have even gone so far as to manually delete it to get this to run to no avail. I have searched but can't seem to see where my problem lies.

Also this file is named `mysql4-upgrade-0.1.22-0.1.23.php` and currently the core_resource for this shows 0.1.22 so this should be running. And, maybe it is, and I have another issue?

Can anyone point me at why this might not be running or removing this data?

Comment: have you changed the `<version>` in the config.xml to `0.1.23`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for remove attribute

```
 $installer = $this;
 $installer->removeAttribute('customer', 'attribute_code_here');
```